SwiftData: _InvalidFutureBackingData.getValue<A>(forKey:) when accessing model property
I'm seeing this error quite regularly when accessing properties of SwiftData models.
Here's one example of the stack trace:
_InvalidFutureBackingData.getValue<A>(forKey:) + 268 (BackingData.swift:866)
protocol witness for BackingData.getValue<A>(forKey:) in conformance _InvalidFutureBackingData<A> + 24 (<compiler-generated>:0)
PersistentModel.getValue<A>(forKey:) + 232 (PersistentModel.swift:62)
Video.updatedDate.getter
MyVideoActor.refresh(subscriptionId:) 
...

I am assuming the model may have been deleted in between fetching it and accessing its data? The root cause could be somewhere else, but here is my basic structure.

Basic Structure
Assuming I have a list of Subscription models and can refresh them to fetch new Videos:
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @State var refresher = MyRefreshManager()
    @Query var subscriptions: [Subscription]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(subscriptions) { sub in
                Button("Refresh Sub") {
                    handleRefresh(sub.persistentModelID)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            refresher.container = modelContext.container
        }
    }
        
    func handleRefresh(_ persistentId: PersistentIdentifier) {
        refresher.refresh(persistentId)
    }
}

I'm using an observed object that takes care of refreshing. For it to run in the background, I also have a ModelActor that I initiate on the background thread (otherwise it doesn't actually run in the background).
@Observable class MyRefreshManager {
    weak var container: ModelContainer?
    
    func refresh(_ subscriptionId: PersistentIdentifier) {
        guard let container else { return }
        Task.detached {
            let actor = MyVideoActor(modelContainer: container)
            await actor.refresh(subscriptionId)
        }
    }
}

@ModelActor actor VideoActor {
    func refresh(_ subscriptionId: PersistentIdentifier) async {
        guard let subscription = modelContext.model(for: subscriptionId) as? Subscription else {
            return
        }
        
        let newVideos = await loadNewVideos(for: subscription)
        
        let existingVideos = subscription.videos ?? []
        for video in existingVideos {
            print(video.updatedDate)
            // ^ Error here: _InvalidFutureBackingData.getValue<A>(forKey:) ...
        }
        // ...
        try? modelContext.save()
    }
    
    func loadNewVideos(for subscription: Subscription) async -> [SendableVideo] {
        // ...
        return []
    }
}

SwiftData Models
@Model
class Subscription {
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Video.subscription)
    public var videos: [Video]? = []
    public var url: URL?
    
    init() { }
}

@Model
class Video {
    public var subscription: Subscription?
    var updatedDate: Date?
    
    init() { }
}

Is there something wrong with this approach that could be causing the crash? What could I do differently to avoid it if that is the case? Thanks :)

"I am assuming the model may have been deleted", where do you delete objects? I can't reproduce this using the given code bit I still have to wonder why you have ModelContainer as a weak var in your observable class or even as a property at all there? You could pass it as an argument to the refresh for instance or keep a singleton reference to it.

I can’t reliably reproduce it either, but I often see this error in crash reports. The actual project is on GitHub if that helps. It happens in various places where properties are accessed, both inside and outside an actor. Models might be deleted via sync or from a user action during the refresh. Having the container in the observable class makes it easier, as a refresh can be triggered in different places. Are you saying a singleton for the container makes more sense instead of using modelContext.container?
